# Rails ActiveRecord equivalent of Laravel ORM `attach()` method for polymorphic has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eloquent, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm transitioning from "Laravel ORM" to "Rails Active Record" and I couldn't find how do you do something like this:

```
$this->people()->attach($person['id'], ['role' => $role]);
```

**Explanation for Laravel code snippet**

`People` is a polymorphic association to the class that is being accessed via `$this`  via the `Role` class. The function above, creates a record in the middle table (roles/peopleables) like this:

```
id: {{generically defined}}
people_id: $person['id']
role: $role
peopleable_type: $this->type
peopleable_id: $this->id
```

How the association is defined on the Laravel end:

```
class XYZ {
...
    public function people()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(People::class, 'peopleable')->withPivot('role','id');
    }
...
}
```

**My efforts in Ruby**

Here is how I made the association in Ruby:

```
class Peopleable < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :people
    belongs_to :peopleable, polymorphic: true
end

class People < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :peopleables
end

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

I have seen the operation `<<` but I don't know if there is any way to set an additional value on the pivot table while triggering this operation. [in this case the `roles` or `peopleables` tables; I use these two terms interchangeably in this app.]

PS. So, basically the question is how to define additional values on the pivot table in a polymorphic-many association in ActiveRecord and dynamically set those values while initiating an attachment relationship

### Description of Functionality

Our application has a limitless [generally speaking, not that there is no computational limits!] content type: post, novel, poem, etc.

Each of these content types can be associated to individuals who play certain roles: editor, author, translator, etc.

So, for example:

> X is the translator of Post#1. X, Y and Z are authors of Post#1.

There is a distinct `People` model and each content type has its own unique model [for example: `Post`, `Poem`, etc].

The idea of *:through* is referring to the '`Role` class' or 'the pivot table' [whichever way you want to understand it] that the polymorphic association is recorded on it.

In addition to the information regarding a simple polymorphic relationship, there is also the kind of role that is recorded on the pivot table.

For example, X is both the author and the translator for Post#1, so there are two rows with the same `people_id`, `peopleable_type` and `peopleable_id`, however they have different values for `role`.

Comment: in Rails *able classes are not real classes, they are abstractions used for polymorphic relationships. The way it works is that the child class, contains both the id of the parent and the class of the parent. Where a non-polymorphic class would only hold the id of the parent it belongs to. Then, back to your case, we wouldn't have any "Peoplable" class defined per se.

Comment: The title says `has_many :through` but your code is not a `has_many :through` association. Can you explain your expected assocaitions? Do you want to associate a person with multiple people? Read this too https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @arieljuod I added "Description of Functionality". I understand this is a strange way of doing things, but there are reasons for doing it – though I welcome feedbacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand given your description, I think you have this models (I'll change the names to what I understand they are, hope it's clear enough):

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord # using singular for models
  has_many :person_roles
end

class Poem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :person_roles, as: :content
end

class Novel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :person_roles, as: :content
end

etc...

class PersonRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true

  # you should have a "role" column on your table
end
```

So a Person is associated to a "content" (Novel, Poem, etc) via the join model PersonRole with a specific role. A Person that is the author of some novel and the editor of some peom would have two PersonRole records.

So, if you have a person and you want to assign a new role on some content, you can just do:

```
person.person_roles.create(role: :author, content: some_poem)

or

PersonRole.create(person: person, role: :author, content: some_poem)

or

some_poem.person_roles.create(person: person, role: :author)
```

You have two things in play here: "belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true" is covers the part of this being a polymorphic association. Then you have the "PersonRole" table that covers the part you know as "pivot table" (join table/model on rails).

Note that `:through` in rails has other meaning, you may want to get all the poems that a user is an author of, you could then have a "has_many :poems, through: :person_roles" association (that won't actually work, it's more complex than that in this case because you have a polymorphic association, you'll need to configure the association with some extra options like `source` and `scope` for this to work, I'm just using it as an example of what we understand as a `has many :through` association).

Comment: Thanks man!, it saved a lot of time. It is funny that though Ruby & PHP look very similar, in doing complex tasks, the end solution could seem this different!

Answer (score 0):

1. Rails is 'convention over configuration'. Models' must be in singular 'Person'.
2. ActiveRecord has has_many ... through and polymorphic association
3. "Assignable" and "Assignments" are more natural to read than "peoplable"

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, as: :assignable
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :people, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :assignable, polymorphic: true
end
```

You can read more [Rails has_many :through Polymorphic Association by Sean C Davis](https://cobwwweb.com/rails-has-many-through-polymorphic-association)